# How to display the special value always at top while sorting?

Tags: perl, sorting, hash-reference

I used the below code to sort values and display it as a dropdown in a Perl form page And I need to display a certain value always at the top of the sorted list, how to do that?

```
 values= [sort {$a<=>$b and $orig->{$a} cmp $orig->{$b}} keys  %$orig]
```

I tried this too,not working with me for some reason

```
values= [sort {if ($a eq 'somevalue') { return 1; }
elsif ($b eq 'somevalue') { return -1; }
else { return {$a<=>$b and $orig->{$a} cmp $orig->{$b}} keys  %$orig ;} }]
```

Any help?

Comment: So the keys of `$orig` are numbers (that you compare with `<=>`) and the values are strings (that you compare with `cmp`)? That's not implausible, but it is unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort `$special` value like the lowest using `(($b eq $special) - ($a eq $special))` as the first link in "s**OR**t chain":

```
my $special = "somevalue";
sort { (($b eq $special) - ($a eq $special)) || 
       $a<=>$b || $orig->{$a} cmp $orig->{$b} } keys  %$orig;
```

---

`(($b eq $special) - ($a eq $special))` returns:
`0` when $a and $b are special [$a is equal $b]
`-1` when $a is special and $b is not [$a less than $b]
`+1` when $b is special and $a is not [$a greater than $b]
`0` when both $a and $b are not special [$a is equal $b]

When it produces 0 next links in the s**OR**t chain are queried.

Comment: It's almost working,But the  problem is it's messing the  sort order which I want. [sort{$a<=>$b and $orig->{$a} cmp $orig->{$b}} keys  %$orig ] This is the sort order i want with some value at the top.But your answer is giving that somevalue at the top with ASCII sorting

Comment: Could you provide sample hash with sorting output you expect?

Answer (score 0):

slice the 1st element before sort than put it back before display, like

```
my @foo = ( header, 4, 5, 6 );
$bar = shift(@foo);

# sort it or do what you want

unshift(@foo,$bar);

print @foo, "\n";
```

Comment: That' would be fine if I want to display the first value of the hash ref.Unfortunately I don't know at what position or index my value is there .I only know it's value i.e,"somevalue" and I am sorting and printing in a form feild bdw so I can't explicitly use print here!!

Comment: Oh. I was sure you need the header at the top, as you mentioned: "certain value always at the top of the sorted list" ... and I assumed (incorrectly) it is originally in the top.

Comment: yes,I do the need the header at the top and even I wouldn't know where it would be..Refer the above answer and Do you think that you can modify that answer according to  my question and provide me a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your hash contains only non-negative keys, you
can sort the header values as if they were -∞
which will sort before anything else, but will be equal to
itself

```
sort {
    my ($aa, $bb) = map { $_ eq $special ? -Inf : $_ } $a, $b;
    $aa <=> $bb and $orig->{$aa} cmp $orig->{$bb};
} keys %$orig;
```